# Parent div with margin and with auto and child with 100% do not fill full width

Tags: html, css, width

What I would like to do is to create a menu which fills all width but some margin at left and right.
This is the structure:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="element">
            <a><p>Text1</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            <a><p>Text2</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="element"> 
            <a><p>Text3</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            <a><p>Text4</p></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the css:

```
.parent
{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
.content
{
    width:auto;
    margin:0 20px;
    float:left;
    border-top:1px solid;
    border-left:1px solid;
    border-right:1px solid;
}
.element
{
    width:100%;
    float:left
}
.element a
{
    width:auto;
    padding:10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
}
```

The structure would be the full div and margins on left and right but the div itself with borders has to fill the other part of the page

Here is the example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nSEj/445/)

Comment: You can give diagram structure of what you are expecting

Comment: Change `width:auto;` by `width:100%;` and remove margin  to  your `.content`

Comment: The [auto] tag is specific to C++11 and does not apply her and has been removed. Please be mindful of how you tag your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove `float:left;` from `.parent`, `.content` and `.element` elements. It gonna make everything 100% wide. Actually you don't need styling for `.element` at all, at least for what you asked for.

You already have *some* margin on the left and right of `.content`, so you don't need to change anything here.

```css
.content {
  margin: 0 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}
.element a {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="element">
      <a>
        <p>Text1</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
      <a>
        <p>Text2</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
      <a>
        <p>Text3</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
      <a>
        <p>Text4</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(I also removed `width: auto;` from `.content` element as it's not needed)